# Login and get source code

Tags: android

I'm trying to login to a website and show it's source code using android emulator but I can't make it work but in java based only, it's working.

Here's my code:

```
package auth.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
// used for interacting with user interface
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
// used for passing data 
// used for connectivity
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class AuthActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

//Handler h;
private static URL URLObj;
private static URLConnection connect;
EditText eText;
TextView tView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

   tView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   initControls();
}

    public void initControls()
    {

        try {

            URLObj = new URL("http://students.usls.edu.ph");
            connect = URLObj.openConnection();
            connect.setDoOutput(true);  
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            tView.setText("The URL specified was unable to be parsed or uses an invalid protocol. Please try again.");
            //System.exit(1); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            tView.setText("An exception occurred. " + ex.getMessage());
            //System.exit(1);
        }


        try {

            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream()));
            writer.write("username=0920204&password=******");
            //writer.close();


            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));

            String lineRead="";


            while((lineRead=reader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                tView.append(lineRead + "\n");
            }


            reader.close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            tView.setText("There was an error reading or writing to the URL: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

So, instead of showing the source code of the main page, it's showing the source code of the login page. So I think there's something wrong with the Bufferedwriter part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should hide username/ password or fake them.

`URLConnection` handles cookies very bad. That's why you just got the results from login page. Android has [Apache HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) built-in since API 1, so you can use it. Cookies are managed very well  :-)

And, you're getting the raw text responded from server, not the source code.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the form is, according to the page source, `login.cfm` So you should post there, you can use  this as an example: http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/18188